# how to create RecycleView on This data table in kivy python?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

i have a data table that contains a 50 rows and i need to display all rows in the page but when click check box that check all the app is crashed until i make a Recycle View on The row_data how can i make this?

```
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.datatables import MDDataTable


class Example(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        layout = AnchorLayout()
        data_tables = MDDataTable(
            size_hint=(0.9, 0.6),
            background_color=(1,.1,1,1),
            check=True,
            rows_num = 50,
            column_data=[
                ("No.", dp(30)),
                ("Column 1", dp(30)),
                ("Column 2", dp(30)),
                ("Column 3", dp(30)),
                ("Column 4", dp(30)),
                ("Column 5", dp(30)),
            ],
            row_data=[
                (f"{i + 1}", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5") for i in range(50)
            ],
        )
        layout.add_widget(data_tables)
        return layout


Example().run()
```

Comment: Try decreasing the value of `rows_num`.

Comment: My app need to be rows_num =50

Comment: Did you try with `use_pagination = True` ?

Comment: yes but the crash is still ? i found that if the rows_num > 10 (the default value) it will be crashed do you know how to change the default from the libirary

Comment: I'm not sure but the code seems to be broken. It uses `RecycleView` for the data table, the process for whenever the items goes out of the screen (viewport actually) is not implemented properly, I think. You may post this issue on GitHub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed it
the problem was that when increase rows_num more than 10 the application was crashed
the fix was to replace the kivymd from pypi module to github kivymd module and it will fix all the module problems